# Convert do/while into parallel do/while loop

Tags: c++, openmp, do-while

I'm having trouble converting a `do/while{}` into OpenMP. I'm following [Example: While Loop](https://www.cac.cornell.edu/vw/openmp/whileloop.aspx) from Cornell's Virtual Workshop.

Here is the original `do/while{}`. The variables `r`, `re` and `modn` are just Crypto++ classes. `r` and `re` are [`Integers`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html), while `modn` is a [`ModularArithmetic`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_modular_arithmetic.html). `Randomize` creates an integer in the specified range.

```
do {
    r.Randomize(rng, Integer::One(), m_n - Integer::One(), Integer::ANY);
    rInv = modn.MultiplicativeInverse(r);
} while (rInv.IsZero() || (Jacobi(r % m_p, m_p) == -1) || (Jacobi(r % m_q, m_q) == -1));
```

The parallelizable part is the two Jacobi tests after the random number is generated. Jacobi is cheaper (***O(m·log(n))***) than modular inversion (***O(n^2)***). Also, Jacobi fails 75% of the time, so I should perform the Jacobi tests before spending cycles on the modular inversion.

Here is what I have translated it to. **EDIT**: The outer `#pragma omp parallel private(stop) { ... }` was removed. Please check history if kfsone's answer does not make sense.

```
bool stop = false;
while(!stop)
{
    r.Randomize(rng, Integer::One(), m_n - Integer::One());        

    int jp, jq;
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
            jp = Jacobi(r % m_p, m_p);
        #pragma omp section
            jq = Jacobi(r % m_q, m_q);
    }

    if ((jp != -1) && (jq != -1))
    {
        rInv = modn.MultiplicativeInverse(r);

        if(rInv.NotZero()) {
            stop = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The self tests succeed with the non-OMP version, but fail with the OMP version, so I know something is wrong.

What am I doing wrong in the OMP version of the `do/while{}`?

Comment: `private(stop)` each thread has it's own instance of `stop`... meanwhile `jp` and `jq` appear to be shared (?), which is going to be a problem...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3dabskb.aspx

Comment: Far from a wiz, I gave you all the openmp I remember and half of it was wrong, hehe. Answer otw, takes a moment on the kindle :)

Comment: What is this loop doing? It looks to me like it just generates random numbers and stops generating them when the condition is met. The result is `rInv` when the condition is met. Is that all you want? `rInv` with that condition?

Comment: If that's the case why not just generate random numbers and a private `rInv` but a shared test to break from a while loop. If you end up with multiple `rInv` choose any of them.

Comment: @Zboson -  I clarified the question. I added some context like running times, and the order in which I want to perform the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `private(stop)` tells omp to give each thread a unique instance of `stop`, rather than sharing a communal value.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3dabskb.aspx

Remove that or explicitly specify it as shared.

Comment: Getting back to the `jp` and `jq`, what should I do? Decalre them outside the `#pragma omp parallel`? And do they need to be flushed? (Those should be my last questions related to the snippet).

Comment: Hoist the if that uses them inside the parallel sections, and mark them private, each thread should have its own instance.

Comment: Thanks kfsone. I updated the code with what I have. I removed the `#pragma omp parallel private(stop)`, so I don't believe there's a need. Does it look OK to you? (I ordered the OpenMP books tonight. I should have them in a few days).